# Solr: exclude parts of url

Tags: url, solr, filtering

I have a field url in schema.xml. I need to separate my search results based on this field.

For example

- in one search I want results of **www.example.com/part1/** actually all results that have this prefix.
- for another search I want results from **www.example.com**, but without all documents containing **/part1/** in their url.

How can I achieve this? fq doesn't accept special characters and I don't want to split content with NGramFilterFactory, so that this behaviour should be only at search-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory should do what you need, I believe. It splits a path-type string into multiple tokens, building up from the root forwards. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer for more details.

You can then do a query such as `q=path:www.example.com -path:*/part1`, assuming that you are using the Path Hierarchy Tokenizer for both index and query analysis on that field.

Comment: Also [Javadoc for the Tokenizer](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/path/PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory.html) has some nuances showing when to use it as index-only or as search-only.

Comment: nice, thank you guys for your help. Sounds very promissing :)